Error starting next js app with @tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu on wsl
So i installed wsl, nvidia cuda, created next js project in linux subsystem, installed @tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu and to this moment everything was fine, but while starting App i got this error
 ✓ Starting...
 ✓ Ready in 12.9s
 ○ Compiling / ...
 ⨯ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!doctype html>
| <html>
| <head>

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
./node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu/dist/index.js
./src/app/page.tsx
 ⨯ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!doctype html>
| <html>
| <head>

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
./node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu/dist/index.js
./src/app/page.tsx
 ⨯ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!doctype html>
| <html>
| <head>

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
./node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu/dist/index.js
./src/app/page.tsx
 GET / 500 in 31328ms

page.tsx:
import styles from "./page.module.css";

export default function Home() {
  const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu');

  // Define a simple model.
  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 100, activation: 'relu', inputShape: [10]}));
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, activation: 'linear'}));
  model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError'});
  
  const xs = tf.randomNormal([100, 10]);
  const ys = tf.randomNormal([100, 1]);
  
  // Train the model.
  model.fit(xs, ys, {
    epochs: 100,
    callbacks: {
      onEpochEnd: (epoch: any, log: any) => console.log(`Epoch ${epoch}: loss = ${log.loss}`)
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className={styles.page}>
      <h1>Linux ML</h1>
    </div>
  );
}


I tried resolving it with chat gpt and done given me steps few times and it didn't work,
theese steps i tried was, adding webpack config to next.config.mjs, installing some loaders, added some no loading config in next.config, after changing that config I started getting some errors about missing modules. Error there is first error because i created new project.

I had the same error, any luck fixing it?
